# Convert func to string literal in golang

Tags: go

I have some func saved in a variable and I need to convert it into a string literal:

```
testFunc := func(orgId int64) bool {
    return false
}
```

The expected result string literal is like this:

```
resultStr := `func(orgId int64) bool {
    return false
}`
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
testFuncStr := reflect.ValueOf(testFunc).String()
```

However this only get me the following literal:

```
"<func(int64) bool Value>",
```

Comment: Go is a compiled language. You cannot recover the source from a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BurakSerdar said - Go is not a language which is interpreted, but compiled, so there's rather limited amount of stuff you can do. [`reflect`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) is a powerful package - you can get function names, number of function arguments, and even call stack (which is handy for logging), but you will never be able to obtain a source code of a function from within a build binary.